# Need some help using widgets with wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, pygame, wxwidgets

Hey i am using pygame within wxpython, and I am wondering how can I use a wx widget inside the pygame part of the program.

So, I would just like to replace the player image with a wxButton. (So when you press LEFT the button will move left, ect). The player image is player.png and the other image is bad.png

```
import wx, sys, os, pygame, random

class PygameDisplay(wx.Window):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID):
        wx.Window.__init__(self, parent, ID)

WINDOWWIDTH = 600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 40
BADDIEMINSIZE = 10
BADDIEMAXSIZE = 40
BADDIEMINSPEED = 1
BADDIEMAXSPEED = 8
ADDNEWBADDIERATE = 6
PLAYERMOVERATE = 5

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
    for b in baddies:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Dodger')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

# set up fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up sounds

# set up images
playerImage = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('bad.png')

# show the "Start" screen
drawText('Dodger', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()


topScore = 0
while True:
    # set up the start of the game
    baddies = []
    score = 0
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    reverseCheat = slowCheat = False
    baddieAddCounter = 0

    while True: # the game loop runs while the game part is playing
        score += 1 # increase score

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = True
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                # If the mouse moves, move the player where the cursor is.
                playerRect.move_ip(event.pos[0] - playerRect.centerx, event.pos[1] - playerRect.centery)

        # Add new baddies at the top of the screen, if needed.
        if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
            baddieAddCounter += 1
        if baddieAddCounter == ADDNEWBADDIERATE:
            baddieAddCounter = 0
            baddieSize = random.randint(BADDIEMINSIZE, BADDIEMAXSIZE)
            newBaddie = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-baddieSize), 0 - baddieSize, baddieSize, baddieSize),
                        'speed': random.randint(BADDIEMINSPEED, BADDIEMAXSPEED),
                        'surface':pygame.transform.scale(baddieImage, (baddieSize, baddieSize)),
                        }

            baddies.append(newBaddie)

        # Move the player around.
        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)

        # Move the mouse cursor to match the player.
        pygame.mouse.set_pos(playerRect.centerx, playerRect.centery)

        # Move the baddies down.
        for b in baddies:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

         # Delete baddies that have fallen past the bottom.
        for b in baddies[:]:
            if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                baddies.remove(b)

        # Draw the game world on the window.
        windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)

        # Draw the score and top score.
        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, windowSurface, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, windowSurface, 10, 40)

        # Draw the player's rectangle
        windowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)

        # Draw each baddie
        for b in baddies:
            windowSurface.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])

        pygame.display.update()

        # Check if any of the baddies have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score # set new top score
            break

        mainClock.tick(FPS)

    # Stop the game and show the "Game Over" screen.

    drawText('GAME OVER', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()


    def Update(self, event)
        # Any update tasks would go here (moving sprites, advancing animation frames etc.)
        self.Redraw()

    def Redraw(self):
        if self.size_dirty:
            self.screen = pygame.Surface(self.size, 0, 32)
            self.size_dirty = False

        self.screen.fill((0,0,0))
        cur = 0
        w, h = self.screen.get_size()
        while cur <= h:
            pygame.draw.aaline(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, h - cur), (cur, 0))
            cur += self.linespacing

        s = pygame.image.tostring(self.screen, 'RGB')
        img = wx.ImageFromData(self.size[0], self.size[1], s)
        bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(img)
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, False)
        del dc

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        self.Redraw()

    def OnSize(self, event):
        self.size = self.GetSizeTuple()
        self.size_dirty = True

    def Kill(self, event):

        # Make sure Pygame can't be asked to redraw /before/ quitting by unbinding all methods which
        # call the Redraw() method
        # (Otherwise wx seems to call Draw between quitting Pygame and destroying the frame)
        self.Unbind(event = wx.EVT_PAINT, handler = self.OnPaint)
        self.Unbind(event = wx.EVT_TIMER, handler = self.Update, source = self.timer)


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.display = PygameDisplay(self, -1)
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.statusbar.SetFieldsCount(3)
        self.statusbar.SetStatusWidths([-3, -4, -2])
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText("wxPython", 0)
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText("Look, it's a nifty status bar!!!", 1)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.Kill)

        self.curframe = 0
        self.SetTitle("Pygame embedded in wxPython")
        self.slider = wx.Slider(self, wx.ID_ANY, 5, 1, 10, style = wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.slider.SetTickFreq(0.1, 1)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnScroll)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.Update, self.timer)

        self.timer.Start((1000.0 / self.display.fps))

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.slider, 0, flag = wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.display, 1, flag = wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

    def Kill(self, event):
        self.display.Kill(event)
        self.Destroy()

    def OnSize(self, event):
        self.Layout()

    def Update(self, event):
        self.curframe += 1
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText("Frame %i" % self.curframe, 2)

    def OnScroll(self, event):
        self.display.linespacing = self.slider.GetValue()


class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = Frame(parent = None)
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use wxPython wigits *inside* pygame. There are GUI modules that you can use.

http://www.pygame.org/tags/gui

Google summer of code has a project working on a better GUI too.

Comment: Hes using pygame inside wxpython, it works, but it is really buggy